# Having trouble getting my Tic Tac Toe app in android studio to work correctly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have designed a Tic Tac Toe application on android studio for my app dev class this semester. I first had an issue with my code crashing due to the OnClickListener which I resolved by fixing the buttonMatrix with correct values. My code now opens and runs but I'm having an issue getting my game to advance to the next turn in the game. Basically my app runs and I press the buttons where I want to place either an 'X' or 'O' value depending on if it's player 1 or player 2's turn. My current code only places X's and doesn't advance to player 2's turn and it also doesn't apply my win conditions when I get 3 X's in a row. My current code is as follows:

MainActivity.Java:

```
package com.example.corey.tictactoegame;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;




class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener 
{


    private Button[][] buttonMatrix = new Button[3][3];




    private boolean p1Turn = true;

    private int turnAdvance;
    private int player1Score;
    private int player2Score;


    TextView textViewP1;
    TextView textViewP2;
    TextView gameStatus;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //IDs the TextViews containing player scores//
        textViewP1 = findViewById(R.id.p1Score);
        textViewP2 = findViewById(R.id.p2Score);




        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {



                String buttonID = "button_" + i + j;
                int resourceID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", 
                    getPackageName());
                buttonMatrix[i][j] = findViewById(resourceID);
                buttonMatrix[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);

            }
        }


        // creating the click functionality for the New Game Button//
        Button newGameButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonNewGame);
        newGameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                newGameReset();

            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    //Checks to see if button pressed is an empty button or a
    // previously used button and returns a value if
    // empty depending on player turn//

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (!((Button) view).getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return;
        }
        turnAdvance = 0;
        // Creates text values for the buttons with either "X" or "O" depending on player turn//
        if (p1Turn) {
            ((Button) view).setText("X");
            turnAdvance++;


        }

        else {
            ((Button) view).setText("O");
            turnAdvance++;
        }


        //advances the round after a turn from both players//
        turnAdvance++;


    }

    // creating the win method based on conditions within the matrix as stated below//
    private boolean winConditions() {
        String[][] matrix = new String[3][3];


        if (winConditions()) {
            if (p1Turn) {
                p1Wins();
            } else {
                p2Wins();
            }
            //ends game in a draw if 9 turns are made//
            if (turnAdvance == 9) {
                gameDraw();
            }
            //ends the turnAdvance function//
            else {
                p1Turn = !p1Turn;
            }

        }

        //creating the win conditions for the game covering all
        // horizontal, vertical, and diagonal possibilities//


        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = buttonMatrix[i][j].getText().toString();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (matrix[i][0].equals(matrix[i][1])
                    && matrix[i][0].equals(matrix[i][2])
                    && !matrix[i][0].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (matrix[0][i].equals(matrix[1][i])
                    && matrix[0][i].equals(matrix[1][i])
                    && !matrix[0][i].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (matrix[0][0].equals(matrix[1][1])
                && matrix[0][0].equals(matrix[2][2])
                && !matrix[0][0].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }
        if (matrix[0][2].equals(matrix[1][1])
                && matrix[0][2].equals(matrix[2][0])
                && !matrix[0][2].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;


    }

    //creating a method to clear the board when a game ends//
    private void boardClear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                buttonMatrix[i][j].setText("");
            }
        }

        turnAdvance = 0;
        p1Turn = true;

    }

    //creating a method to set the score text for each player//
    private void updateScoreText() {
        textViewP1.setText("Player One (X): " + player1Score);
        textViewP2.setText("Player Two (O): " + player2Score);
    }

    //creating a method to reset all score values and clear board//
    private void newGameReset() {
        player1Score = 0;
        player2Score = 0;
        updateScoreText();
        boardClear();
    }

    //creating a method for player one winning//
    private void p1Wins() {
        player1Score++;
        gameStatus.setText("Player One (X) Wins!");
        updateScoreText();
        boardClear();
    }

    //creating a method for player two winning//
    private void p2Wins() {
        player2Score++;
        gameStatus.setText("Player Two (O) Wins!");
        updateScoreText();
        boardClear();
    }

    //creating a method for the game ending in a draw//
    private void gameDraw() {
        gameStatus.setText("Game Draw!");
        boardClear();
    }


    protected void savedState(Bundle currentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(currentState);

        currentState.putInt("turnAdvance", turnAdvance);
        currentState.putInt("player1Score", player1Score);
        currentState.putInt("player2Score", player2Score);
        currentState.putBoolean("p1Turn", p1Turn);
    }

    protected void restoredState(Bundle newState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(newState);

        turnAdvance = newState.getInt("turnAdvance");
        player1Score = newState.getInt("player1Score");
        player2Score = newState.getInt("player2Score");
        p1Turn = newState.getBoolean("p1Turn");
    }
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="136dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/p1Score"
        android:layout_width="187dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Player One (X): 0"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:freezesText="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/p2Score"
        android:layout_width="187dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/p1Score"
        android:text="Player Two (O): 0"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:freezesText="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gameOutcome"
        android:layout_width="329dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonNewGame"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="28sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonNewGame"
        android:layout_width="141dp"
        android:layout_height="82dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="New Game"
        android:textSize="24sp" />


</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_00"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:freezesText="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_01"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:freezesText="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_02"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:freezesText="true"/>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:freezesText="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_11"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:freezesText="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_12"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:freezesText="true"/>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_20"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:freezesText="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_21"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:freezesText="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_22"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:freezesText="true"/>


</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Not looking for you to do my homework assignment for me but I think it's a simple fix that I'm just overthinking/overlooking and would love for this to work correctly before I submit

Thanks!!

CW

Comment: You might want to highlight one or more specific problems in your code, rather than just telling us that your code isn't working.

Comment: At the top of my question I stated what issues I was having. Sorry I didn't highlight for you but someone else was able to comment and provide help without the snobby comment. I am new to stack overflow so my question layouts aren't perfect as you can see by my 6 reputation. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I didn't mean at all to be rude to you.  I just felt that your question was a bit broad, and if you narrowed it down it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Sorry I've just seen many other rude posts on here and more often than not I've seen rude comments. Thanks for assisting me on bettering future questions I may have :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in your `onClick` function you're checking if p1turn is true but never changing p1turn to false, hence it's always their turn.  Second, the only spot you're calling `winConditions()` in inside `winConditions()` so the function is never used.

Comment: Awesome. Okay so now I moved my statement:

    if (winConditions()) {
            if (p1Turn) {
                p1Wins();
            } else {
                p2Wins();
            }
            //ends game in a draw if 9 turns are made//
            if (turnAdvance == 9) {
                gameDraw();
            }
            //ends the turnAdvance function//
            else {
                p1Turn = !p1Turn;
            }

        }

So that the function is being used. It now terminates the app when player 1 wins the game instead of displaying a victory. Where would I

Comment: ADD in the p1Turn = false; statement?

Comment: I would move the line `p1Turn = !p1Turn;` from `winConditions()` to the bottom of `onClick` , that way every time you click the turn is swapped.

Comment: Okay that worked and now allows the turns to swap. Now the problem is it starts at p2Turn instead of p1Turn because it places "O" first 

- and upon winConditions being met, it terminates the application.  (I can relink the new .java and .xml if you need to see an updated layout)

Comment: I have been fiddling around with my code and I got the order of turns correct. Now my only issue is the app randomly terminating either when someone wins or occasionally in the middle of a game with no results yet. Any thoughts on what might be causing that?

Comment: There should be an error message displayed in the Logcat of Android Studio when it's crashing,  could you share the error?

Comment: I had to create another answer for my question to copy and paste the entire logcat from first line to first line. Check there please and thank you!

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what that error means, it looks like it has something to do with the microphone and totally unrelated to your application.  I would suggest creating a new question to get help with it.

Comment: I actually just got on again to look at it and this time I got a different error. I will edit post above and replace with new logcat if you would like to take a look. It seems like it has something to do with p2Turn and p2Wins

Comment: Ah ok, that one makes more sense.  So you have your three TextViews:     textViewP1, textViewP2 and gameStatus.  But you're only initializing the first two in `onCreate()` as in `textViewP1 = findViewById(R.id.p1Score);
 textViewP2 = findViewById(R.id.p2Score);`.  So you should just need to add `gameStatus = findViewById(R.id.???)` for whatever resource id the gameStatus TextView uses.

Comment: Awesome help! I finally got it running and functioning almost how I wanted it to! The only problem I'm incurring now is it applies winConditions in some situations where there hasn't been a winCondition met. Example, I run my application and put "X" in top left box "O" in top middle box then "X" again in middle left box and it applies a win for "X" even though the player only has two out of three squares with winConditions met. Any clue on that fix? It must be something with my array matrix and my winConditions logic.

Comment: I also had to swap p1Wins and p2Wins in order for the correct winner to be chosen. For example, instead of how the code looks above, it is now:
    if (winConditions()){
        if(p1Turn){
            p2Wins();
       }else{
            p1Wins();
       }

Comment: I posted the updated version of the game as a new answer. We can move the comment section to that if it would be easier for you or we can keep it as one here.

Comment: Actually never mind I figured it out! I had the wrong values within my vertical buttonMatrix[ ][ ] winCondition. It works as is and I'm submitting it lol!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated code. The only issue I am having at this point is winConditions being met before winConditions have actually been met. IE 2 in a row in horizontal and vertical wins. Diagonal wins seem to be working with 3 in a row.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.corey.tictactoegame;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;



//implementing OnClickListener for Buttons//
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //I decided to use a matrix instead of just calling all buttons
    // individually and creating a long list of winConditions.
    // I did do a little more in depth research on using 2D arrays
    // and it took a while to figure this out but I'm glad I did//
    private Button[][] buttonMatrix = new Button[3][3];




    private boolean p1Turn = true;

    private int turnAdvance;
    private int player1Score;
    private int player2Score;


    TextView textViewP1;
    TextView textViewP2;
    TextView gameStatus;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //IDs the TextViews containing player scores and the game outcomes//
        textViewP1 = findViewById(R.id.p1Score);
        textViewP2 = findViewById(R.id.p2Score);
        gameStatus = findViewById(R.id.gameOutcome);




        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {



                String buttonID = "button_" + i + j;
                int resourceID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
                buttonMatrix[i][j] = findViewById(resourceID);
                buttonMatrix[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);

            }
        }


        // creating the click functionality for the New Game Button//
        Button newGameButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonNewGame);
        newGameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                newGameReset();

            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    //Checks to see if button pressed is an empty button or a
    // previously used button and returns a value if
    // empty depending on player turn//

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (!((Button) view).getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return;
        }

        // Creates text values for the buttons with either "X" or "O" depending on player turn//
        if (p1Turn) {
            ((Button) view).setText("X");
        }
        else {
            ((Button) view).setText("O");
        }
        //advances turns//
        turnAdvance++;

        //ends game in a draw if 9 turns are made//
        if (turnAdvance == 9) {
                gameDraw();
            }
            else {
                p1Turn = !p1Turn;
            }







        if (winConditions()) {
            if (p1Turn) {
                p2Wins();
            } else {
                p1Wins();
            }




        }





    }

    // creating the win method based on conditions within the matrix as stated below//
    private boolean winConditions() {
        String[][] matrix = new String[3][3];




        //creating the win conditions for the game covering all
        // horizontal, vertical, and diagonal possibilities//


        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = buttonMatrix[i][j].getText().toString();
            }  
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (matrix[i][0].equals(matrix[i][1])
                    && matrix[i][0].equals(matrix[i][2])
                    && !matrix[i][0].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (matrix[0][i].equals(matrix[1][i])
                    && matrix[0][i].equals(matrix[1][i])
                    && !matrix[0][i].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (matrix[0][0].equals(matrix[1][1])
                && matrix[0][0].equals(matrix[2][2])
                && !matrix[0][0].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }
        if (matrix[0][2].equals(matrix[1][1])
                && matrix[0][2].equals(matrix[2][0])
                && !matrix[0][2].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }



    //creating a method to clear the board when a game ends//
    private void boardClear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                buttonMatrix[i][j].setText("");
            }
        }
        //starts game at 0 turns and player 1's turn//
        turnAdvance = 0;
        p1Turn = true;

    }

    //creating a method to set the score text for each player//
    private void updateScoreText() {
        textViewP1.setText("Player One (X): " + player1Score);
        textViewP2.setText("Player Two (O): " + player2Score);
    }

    //creating a method to reset all score values and clear
    // board when the New Game button is pressed//
    private void newGameReset() {
        player1Score = 0;
        player2Score = 0;
        updateScoreText();
        boardClear();
    }

    //creating a method for player one winning//
    private void p1Wins() {
        player1Score++;
        gameStatus.setText("Player One (X) Wins!");
        updateScoreText();
        boardClear();
    }

    //creating a method for player two winning//
    private void p2Wins() {
        player2Score++;
        gameStatus.setText("Player Two (O) Wins!");
        updateScoreText();
        boardClear();
    }

    //creating a method for the game ending in a draw//
    private void gameDraw() {
        gameStatus.setText("Game Draw!");
        boardClear();
    }


    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle currentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(currentState);

        currentState.putInt("turnAdvance", turnAdvance);
        currentState.putInt("player1Score", player1Score);
        currentState.putInt("player2Score", player2Score);
        currentState.putBoolean("p1Turn", p1Turn);
    }

    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle newState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(newState);

        turnAdvance = newState.getInt("turnAdvance");
        player1Score = newState.getInt("player1Score");
        player2Score = newState.getInt("player2Score");
        p1Turn = newState.getBoolean("p1Turn");
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="136dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/p1Score"
            android:layout_width="187dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Player One (X): 0"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:freezesText="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/p2Score"
            android:layout_width="187dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/p1Score"
            android:text="Player Two (O): 0"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:freezesText="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gameOutcome"
            android:layout_width="329dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonNewGame"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonNewGame"
            android:layout_width="141dp"
            android:layout_height="82dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="New Game by Corey Whitlow"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_00"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:freezesText="true"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_01"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:freezesText="true"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_02"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:freezesText="true"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:freezesText="true"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:freezesText="true"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:freezesText="true"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_20"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:freezesText="true"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_21"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:freezesText="true"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_22"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:freezesText="true"/>


    </LinearLayout>








</LinearLayout>
```

I also had to change winConditions where it says:

```
if (winConditions()) {
    if (p1Turn) {
        p2Wins();
    } else {
        p1Wins();
    }

}
```

Essentially I feel like when you read this it says if it's player one's turn player 2 wins which doesn't make sense when read aloud? Not sure why I had to swap that around. Thanks again for being such a tremendous help! I love android and this is the first I've been learning about it this semester LOL! :D